# Converting Dataframe to json format with root level

Tags: python, json, scala, pyspark, databricks

I have a data frame in Databricks with the following data columns

OBJECTID, SingleLine

1234, sample Address

I want to create a JSON output file per the below specification using PySpark or Python / Scala on Databricks Platform
How can I do that ?

```
{

"records": [

    {

        "attributes": {

            "OBJECTID": 1,

            "Address": "380 New York St"

        }

    },

    {

        "attributes": {

            "OBJECTID": 2,

            "Address": "1 World Way"

        }

    }

]
```

Please help ... Thanks very much

Comment: use `json` library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you looking to get all data in above format you can use query below and write it to a file output

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
dfp=spark.createDataFrame([(1,"abc"),(2,"def")],"OBJECTID int, Address string")
dfp.selectExpr(" to_json(map('records',collect_list(map('attriburtes',map('OBJECTID', OBJECTID,'Address', Address))))) as json_output ")

#output
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|json_output                                                                                                    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"records":[{"attriburtes":{"OBJECTID":"1","Address":"abc"}},{"attriburtes":{"OBJECTID":"2","Address":"def"}}]}|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: That worked fine except for one issue now. The object ID is appearing as a string whereas i want it in the Integer format without doublequotes. Any help please ?